# How to JOIN two columns of same table with different filters?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to **join** two **columns** of same table in following way...

QUERY 1 :

```
SELECT MRCY,DT FROM BILLING WHERE BILL_DATE='01-SEP-14' ORDER BY MRCY;
```

QUERY 2 :

```
SELECT DT "OLD DT"  FROM BILLING WHERE BILL_DATE='01-AUG-14' ORDER BY MRCY;
```

How to join output of these query as single result set in Oracle database?
I mean **columns** should apear as follows:

MRCY    DT    OLD DT

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?  The first returns two columns and the second one column.  Sample data and desired results are always useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want the following:

```
SELECT MRCY,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BILL_DATE = DATE '2014-09-01' THEN DT END) as DT,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BILL_DATE = DATE '2014-08-01' THEN DT END) as OLD_DT,
FROM BILLING
WHERE BILL_DATE IN (DATE '2014-09-01', DATE '2014-08-01')
GROUP BY MRCY
ORDER BY MRCY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. Union would remove the duplicates.

But, why would you do that? You can have both filters in the same query.

```
SELECT MRCY , DT 
   FROM BILLING 
 WHERE BILL_DATE IN (to_date('01-SEP-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 
                     to_date('01-AUG-14', 'DD-MON-YYYY') 
 ORDER BY MRCY;
```

Internally, it will be rewritten as an `OR` logic.

Also, note that you are using literal instead of date. And that is incorrect way of dealing with dates. Oracle would do an implicit data conversion. You must always use `TO_DATE`.

And, an year should always be `YYYY` and not just `YY`. Aren't you aware of the Y2K bug?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MRCY, :new_dt as DT, :old_dt "OLD_DT"
  FROM BILLING WHERE BILL_DATE IN (:new_dt, :old_dt)
 ORDER BY MRCY;
```